# Problemas com data PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou usando a seguinte função para me retornar a data corretamente do MySQL para o formato brasileiro:

```
function FormatBR($data){
    $date = date_create($data);
    $date = date_format($date, 'd/m/Y');
    return $date;
}
```

Mas o retorno está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem sabe o que está acontecendo? Ou se estou fazendo da forma errada?

Grato!

Onde crio o JSON:

```
 if (isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id = trim($_GET['id']);
                $sql = "SELECT p.sequencia       codigo, 
                            p.nome_completo   nome,
                            c.cpf             cpf,
                            c.rg                 rg,
                            c.data_nascimento data, 
                            t.celular_1       celular_1,
                            t.celular_2       celular_2,
                            t.celular_3       celular_3,
                            t.telefone_1      telefone_1,
                            t.telefone_2      telefone_2,
                            t.telefone_3      telefone_3,
                            t.status          status_telefone,
                            e.email_1         email_1,
                            e.email_2         email_2,
                            e.status          status_email,
                            d.cep             cep,
                            d.rua             endereco,
                            d.numero          numero,
                            d.bairro          bairro,
                            d.complemento     complemento,
                            d.cidade          cidade,
                            d.estado          estado,
                            d.status          status_end
                        FROM pessoas     p, 
                            clientes     c, 
                            telefones    t,
                            emails       e,
                            enderecos    d
                        WHERE t.cod_pessoa = p.sequencia
                        AND c.cod_pessoa = p.sequencia
                        AND e.cod_pessoa = p.sequencia
                        AND d.cod_pessoa = p.sequencia
                        AND p.sequencia = $id";
                $exec = mysqli_query($link, $sql);     
                if ($exec){
                    while ($clientes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)){
                        $convert = new convertData();    
                        $data_nascimento = $convert->FormatBR($clientes['data']);
                        $vetor[] = array('Codigo' => $clientes['codigo'], 
                                        'Nome' => $clientes['nome'],
                                        'CPF' => $clientes['cpf'],
                                        'RG' => $clientes['rg'],
                                        'Data_Nacimento' => $data_nascimento,
                                        'Celular_1' => $clientes['celular_1'],
                                        'Celular_2' => $clientes['celular_2'],
                                        'Celular_3' => $clientes['celular_3'],
                                        'Telefone_1' => $clientes['telefone_1'],
                                        'Telefone_2' => $clientes['telefone_2'],
                                        'Telefone_3' => $clientes['telefone_3'],
                                        'Status_telefone' => $clientes['status_telefone'],
                                        'email_1' => $clientes['email_1'],
                                        'email_2' => $clientes['email_2'],
                                        'status_email' => $clientes['status_email'],
                                        'cep' => $clientes['cep'],
                                        'endereco' => $clientes['endereco'],
                                        'numero' => $clientes['numero'],
                                        'bairro' => $clientes['bairro'],
                                        'complemento' => $clientes['complemento'],
                                        'estado' => $clientes['estado'],
                                        'status_end' => $clientes['status_end']);
                    }
                }
                echo(json_encode($vetor));
```

Comment: 1995-06-15 (formato US)

Comment: o problema é que ela está me retornando com duas barras \/ (simples e invertida) desta forma: (15\/06\/1995). Sim é um json o retorno. Espero a data no formato BR (15/06/1995)

Comment: Sei que existe a forma de converter isso direto no SQL, mas acaba deixando a instrução mais lenta..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele está retornando o formato "interpretado" pelo json, use o json_decode para manipular:

```
$data = ["Data_Nascimento" => "15/06/1995"];
$data = json_encode($data);
var_dump($data);  // Veja como fica como no exemplo que demonstrou
$dataCorreta = json_decode($data);
echo '<br>Data Formatada: '.$dataCorreta->Data_Nascimento;
```

Comment: Até deu certo, porem, eu estou usando JQUERY.. então no caso teria que usar o json.parse?

Comment: Isso mesmo use o JSON.parse($date).Data_Nascimento